# How to build a release version of react-native Examples

Tags: android, react-native

Now, I can install debug version of react-native examples on my Phone.
follow these steps:

```
./gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug
./packager/packager.sh
```

But  I have to start the server for the app to run correctly.
I want to bundle the js-bundle file to apk and install a release version on my phone. 
And I can demonstrate it to my friends anywhere. 
Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance for your kind help or some hints.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to sign your apk file and add a release build type to your gradle config following the instructions in the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Then, run you packager with `./packager/packager.sh` or simply `npm start`.

The next step is to download the js bundle to the android assets directory. Because there is no `react.gradle` file this needs to be done manually - [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2743):

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false" -o "Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/assets/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle"
```

Finally, you can run the `installRelease` gradle task (or `assembleRelease` and then install the apk manually).

Answer (score 0):

Update on pianiel's answer: The curl command is now

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false" -o "Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/assets/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle"
```

because of changes made to UIExplorer's project structure.